# Django post-save when the superuser is the sender

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I created 3 groups named 'admin', 'teacher' and 'student' and I want every user I register to be in only one of these groups not two.

If i create the super-user by entering in the command line `createsuperuser` it works well, it is added to the 'admin' group, but the problem is that if I create the teacher it is added to the 'teacher' group and also to the 'admin' group and same problem with student.

these is the post-save for my 3 profils

### signals.py

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def admin_profil(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        group = Group.objects.get(name='admin')
        instance.groups.add(group)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Teacher)
def teacher_profil(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        group = Group.objects.get(name='teacher')
        instance.user.groups.add(group)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Student)
def student_profil(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        group = Group.objects.get(name='student')
        instance.user.groups.add(group)
```

Comment: How about checking `instance.is_superuser` in `admin_profil`?

Comment: it works fine, thks